# Search for lowercase then uppercase?

Tags: php

I have a string that is something like

`Firstname LastnameFirstname Lastname`

and I want to convert that to

`Firstname Lastname, Firstname Lastname`

Is there a way in PHP to search for such a character map?

Comment: `Rachel McAdams` should become `Rachel Mc, Adams`?

Comment: What if someone has a last name like McDonald?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Please give more/better examples.

Comment: @Marc&Sam If it was Rachel McAdams, you could split based on the last switch between upper/lower eg: Rachel McAdamsBob Smith would become Rachel McAdams, Bob Smith. Just sayin.

Comment: Lastnames are only a single capital. I will just use PHP to make sure of that. If their last name is as such "McDonald" or "McAdams" I will make it "Mcadams".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a simple/naiive method:

```
$string = preg_replace('/([a-z])([A-Z])/', "$1, $2", $string);
```

but as I put in my comment above, that'll turn `Rachel McAdams` into `Rachel Mc, Adams`.

Comment: If you want to you can add in exceptions like: `/([a-z])(?<!Mc|Mac)([A-Z])/`, Add any exceptions you want in there

Comment: Or use jlis solution like: `/\w*([a-z])([A-Z])/` which will work since the `\w*` is greedy. Unless Rachel McAdams is the final name in the string

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$str = 'Firstname LastnameFirstname Lastname';  // Set our string
$str = preg_replace('/(\w+ \w+[a-z])([A-Z]\w+ \w+)/', '$1, $2', $str);  // Find name boundries and insert comman
echo $str;  // Firstname Lastname, Firstname Lastname
?>
```

Comment: That won't work when you convert it to `preg_replace_all`. If the string has more than two names it will only match every other name.

Comment: I didn't consider that b/c based on the example we were only parsing two names, but that is a very good point.

Answer (score 0):

Detecting uppercase or lowercase isn't so hard. PHP doesn't have a built-in function but you can:

```
$ord = ord($string[$pos]);
$is_uppercase = $ord <= 90 && $ord >= 65;
```

Then you could loop over the characters and see which pairs you find, possibly skipping really 'short' pairs, but that's going to be guess work. There is no perfect way to do this as human names have no set format.

Answer (score 0):

A little complicated but work is done

```
$word = "Firstname LastnameFirstname Lastname";
$word  = str_replace('_', ' ', str_replace('_xx', ', ', strtolower(preg_replace('/[^A-Z^a-z^0-9]+/','_',
        preg_replace('/([a-z\d])([A-Z])/','\1_xx\2',
        preg_replace('/([A-Z]+)([A-Z][a-z])/','\1_\2',$word))))));
echo $word;
```

first preg_replace searches for strings with the uppercase
second searches for strings with uppercase combined with another word
first replace helps to replace our _xx to comma plus space
second replace replace underscore with the space.